# Casting to a String

Tags: java

I am trying to print out the path from one vertex to the other using dijkstra's algorithm. When I send code2 as an argument to List path = ... I get an error on getShortestPathTo saying "The method getShortestPathTo(Digraph.Vertex) in the type Digraph is not applicable for the arguments (String). How can I cast it so that it will accept a String?

```
    System.out.print("City Code: ");
    String code = kb.next();
    String code2 = kb.next(); 
    Digraph.computePaths(Digraph.getCode(source,code));
    List<Digraph.Vertex> path = (Digraph.getShortestPathTo(code2));
```

This is my getShortestPathTo method:

```
 public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target) {
       List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
       for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous) {
           path.add(vertex);
       }
       Collections.reverse(path);
       return path;
   }
```

Comment: Please post the code for Vertex

Comment: What is the variable `kb`?

Comment: @ freakshow1217 I just posted it.

Comment: @ James Smith kb is from Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: What do you need to calculate the shortest route? What parameters do you need?

Comment: @freakshow1217 the parameters for getShortestPathTo is Vertex target

Answer (score 0):

Use Integer.toString("String Here");

Answer (score 0):

The method `getShortestPathTo(Vertex vertex)` requires one parameter, which is a `Vertex`. A `String` is not a `Vertex`. You need to pass a Vertex into the method. You would need to either convert code2 into a `Vertex` with some sort of algorithm (I do not know your `Vertex` formatting), or consider rewriting `kb.next()` to return a Vertex.

Comment: Is there any way I can cast a String into a Vertex?

Comment: @Kay No. Definetly not. `Vertex` is not the superclass of `String`, nor a `subclass`. Make a method to convert `String` to `Vertex`.

Comment: @Kay you have to figure that out on your own. StackOverflow doesn't provide code writing service..